# XGB DataFrame.dtypes error

Tags: pandas, xgboost, dataframe

Here is the code to assign the variables

```
X = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[df['day'], df['spend'], df['platform'],df['month'],df['year']], columns=[['day', 'spend','platform','month','year']])
y = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[df['revenue']], columns=['revenue'])
train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.1, random_state = 123)
```

and following these lines of fitting the model

```
xgb_r = xg.XGBRegressor(objective ='reg:squarederror', booster='gbtree', n_estimators=350, max_depth=10, learning_rate=0.1)
xgb_r.fit(train_X, train_y)
```

I get the following error

```
DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or category. When categorical type is supplied, The experimental DMatrix parameter`enable_categorical` must be set to `True`.  Invalid columns:('day',): object, ('spend',): object, ('platform',): object, ('month',): object, ('year',): object
```

however when I check the datatype with

```
df.dtypes
```

I get the following

```
platform          int64
day               Int64
spend           float64
revenue        float64
year            int64
month           int64
```

Could anyone advise what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

The columns consist of numpy objects, which themselves consist of int or float. Try switching from numpy objects to lists and then create a dataframe from the lists.